# using gsub function in r to remove slash

Tags: r, regex, gsub, string-substitution

suppose I have a string that has the following characters

```
"\"------------080209060700030309080805\""
```

And now I want to use gsub function in r to remove the "\ and \" part, and only keep the following characters:

```
"------------080209060700030309080805\"
```

Could anyone help me to figure out how should I do it properly ?

Comment: `"------------080209060700030309080805\"` as result looks like a typo: Do you really want the final backslash to be part of your result? Please edit your answer...

Comment: Please show us in plain text what the input and output should be.  Don't worry about escaping in R.

Comment: The input here is the exactly looks like this:

"\"------------080209060700030309080805\"", this is actually from a email spam/ham data from a data science book. And I want to use gsub function to only grab the "------------080209060700030309080805"" part, which means I want to get rid of the slash here, but currently it seems i don't have a good way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 1:** Fixed bug (two backslashes required to create a backslash in a string):

```
s <- '\\"------------080209060700030309080805\\"'
s
gsub('\\"', "", s, fixed = TRUE)
```

results in

```
> s <- '\\"------------080209060700030309080805\\"'
> s
[1] "\\\"------------080209060700030309080805\\\""
> gsub('\\"', "", s, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "------------080209060700030309080805"
```

Please note that a single backslash in R is the escape code which is NOT part of the string:

```
> charToRaw('\\"')
[1] 5c 22
> charToRaw('\"')
[1] 22
```

Therefor you have to use two backslashes in the quoted string to create one backslash internally. If you print this string the backslash is escaped again which looks confusing:

```
> print('\\"')
[1] "\\\""
```

If you want to print the unescaped content of the string use `cat` instead of `print`:

```
> cat('\\"')
\"
```

For more see help in R: `?"'"`:

> Character constants
>
> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used
>   interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character
>   constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are
>   normally only used to delimit character constants containing double
>   quotes.
>
> Backslash is used to start an escape sequence inside character
>   constants. Escaping a character not in the following table is an
>   error.
>
> Single quotes need to be escaped by backslash in single-quoted
>   strings, and double quotes in double-quoted strings.
>
> \n     newline \r  carriage return \t  tab \b  backspace \a    alert (bell)
>   \f     form feed \v    vertical tab \     backslash \ \'  ASCII apostrophe '
>   \"     ASCII quotation mark " `   ASCII grave accent (backtick) ` \nnn
>   character with given octal code (1, 2 or 3 digits) \xnn    character
>   with given hex code (1 or 2 hex digits) \unnnn     Unicode character with
>   given code (1--4 hex digits) \Unnnnnnnn    Unicode character with given
>   code (1--8 hex digits)

Answer (score 1):

```
string <- "\\------------080209060700030309080805\\"
string <- gsub("^\\\\(.*)\\\\$", "\\1", string)
```

Notes: The pattern I used was `^\(.*)\$`, which will match everything in between a beginning and ending backslash.  This would only match strings therefore which both begin and end with backslash.  Also, we use four backslashes (`\\\\`) to represent a literal backslash for the pattern in `gsub()`.  We need to escape twice, once for R, and a second time for the regex engine.