# Remove everything after backslash in base R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187552/removing-everything-after-first-backslash-in-a-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42242468/using-gsub-function-in-r-to-remove-slash). However, I can't seem to get them to work for me.

If I have a character vector like:

```
myString <- c("5", "10", "100\abc\nx1\n1")
```

I want to remove everything after (and including) the first backslash. For example, my expected result would be:

```
>myString
"5" "10" "100"
```

I have tried using `sub`, `gsub`, and `strsplit` but I just can't seem to get it to work. Things I've tried:

```
gsub("\\\\*", "", myString)
sub("\\\\.*", "", myString)
gsub('\\"', "", myString, fixed = TRUE)
gsub("\\.*","", myString)
```

But I'm not great with regex stuff so I'm almost definitely not using these functions correctly! Any advice as to how I'd fix this?

Comment: Your `myString` does not contain a `\ `. If it should contain a `\ ` you can use e.g.: `myString <- c("5", "10", "100\\abc\\nx1\\n1")`

Comment: Explanation of why this is happening: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25424382/replace-single-backslash-in-r

Comment: Ah ok... So by my understanding, what I really have in `myString[3]` is separate characters like "100", "\abc", "\nx1", and "\n1". The issue is, Im extracting a giant string from a model output and trying to separate it. So the single backslashes are part of the string I extract

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way you could try:

```
gsub("(^\\d+)([\a-zA-Z0-9]*)", "\\1", myString)

[1] "5"   "10"  "100"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the information from @Skaqqs, it led me to something helpful by @bartektartanus. It's not base R unfortunately, but I think this should work using the stringi package to escape the uniciode

```
library(stringi)
myString <- c("5", "10", "100\abc\nx1\n1")
gsub("\\\\.*", "", stri_escape_unicode(myString))
```

result:

```
 "5"   "10"  "100"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `parse_number`

```
readr::parse_number(myString)
[1]   5  10 100
```